# Regex performance issues - Profanity filter

Tags: java, regex, performance

I'm making a profanity filter (bad idea I know), and I'm trying to do it with regex in Java.

Right now here's my regex example string, this would filter 2 words, foo and bar.

```
(?i)f(?>[.,;:*`'^+~\\/#|]*+|.)o(?>[.,;:*`'^+~\\/#|]*+|.)o|b(?>[.,;:*`'^+~\\/#|]*+|.)a(?>[.,;:*`'^+~\\/#|]*+|.)r
```

Basically, I have it ignore case, then I put `(?>[.,;:*'^+~\\/#|]*+|.)` in between each letter of a curse word, and `|` between each complete curse word regex.

It works, but it's sorta slow.

If I have 6 words in the filter, it will filter a fairly long string (500 characters) in 939,548 nanoseconds. When I have 12, it just about doubles.

So, about 1ms per 6 curse words with this. But my filter will have hundreds (400 or so).
Calculating this, it would take about 66ms to filter this long string.

This is a chat server I'm building, and if I have lots of users on (say, 5,000) and 1 out of 5 are chatting in 1 second (1,000 chat messages) I need to filter a message in about 1ms.

Am I asking too much of regexps? Would it be faster to make my own specialized type of filter by hand? Are there ways to optimize this?

I am precompiling the regex.

If you want to see the effect of this regex http://regexr.com?30454

**Update:** Another thing I could to is have chat messages filtered client side in actionscript.

**Update:** I believe the only way to achieve such degree of performance would be a hand-coded solution without using regexps sadly, so I'll have to do a more basic filter.

Comment: riddle me this.  How would a profanity filter distinguish between the benign "associate" and the profane "asshat"

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem ;)

Comment: @Peter you beat me to it by just seconds ;-)

Comment: I wiSH IT were AS Simple as that, BUT Take my word thaT ITS not.

Comment: Please clarify - are you trying to detect bad words separated by punctuation or are you putting in punctuation to obscure the bad words?

Comment: I am trying to detect bad words when people try to avoid a profanity filter. I'll have a whitelist for the flase positives.

Comment: you should use a white list all the way.  Because what you end up doing is removing words that have multiple meanings, such as the alternate word for rooster.  So you would kind of need a filter around phrases such as rooster sucker.

Comment: Human moderation will go the rest of the way.

Comment: @Woot4Moo That requires a list of all OK words. That will be one h_e_l_l (oops) of a big list!

Comment: I think a whitelist would have poorer performance then a blacklist.

Comment: oops sorry, that is the consultant in me speaking.  Yes a blacklist or a whitelist of bad words if you will =p .

Comment: @Woot4Moo i think these are called blacklist EXCEPTIONS ;)

Comment: @deathApril I am well aware they are called blacklist.  I was making a comment about consultanese.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer your question "am I asking too much of regexps?"- Yes

I spent the better part of 2 years working on a profanity filter using regular expressions and finally gave up. During this time, I tried all of these things:

- Pre-compiling
- Character classes (punctuation, whitespace, etc)
- Non-capturing groups (mentioned above and can greatly reduce memory and increase speed)
- Combining similar regexps (also mentioned above)
- Trimming whitespace (str.trim())
- Case handling (str.toLowerCase())
- Packing and unpacking whitespace (convert multiple adjacent whitespace to a single space and vice-versa)
- Writing my own custom regexp engine (highly unrecommended as it is complex and not scalable)

Nothing worked well and as my blacklist grew my system slowed down. In the end I gave up and implemented a linear analysis filter, which is now the core part of CleanSpeak, [my company's profanity filtering product](https://cleanspeak.com).

We found that we were also able to do some great multi-threading and other optimizations once we stopped using regexps and went from handling 600-700 messages per second to 10,000+ messages per second.

Lastly, we also found that performing linear analysis made the filter more accurate and allowed us to solve the "scunthrope problem" and many of the other ones people have mentioned in the comments here.

You can definitely try all of the things I mention above and see if you can get your performance up, but it is a hard problem to solve because regexps weren't really designed for language analysis. They were designed for text analysis, which is a very different problem.

Comment: I wish I could give more than one upvote, that is very informational.

Comment: I can't seem to find any articles on "linear analysis", recommend any? I'm not sure what you mean by it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't go into it too much since some of it is IP, but I can tell you that linear analysis is the same as single-pass analysis or one-pass analysis. This is something that is used by  [lexical analyzers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis). This is different than regular expressions because each regular expression will perform one pass on the string. Our initial solution ended up doing about 10-20 passes per blacklisted word. With a blacklist of 500 words that was roughly 5,000-10,000 passes. With our current solution we are only performing one pass.

Comment: I have no problem running hundreds of regexes like "\bf+[^a-zA-Z\s]*u+[^a-zA-Z\s]*[ck]*[^a-zA-Z\s]*[ck]+\b" over 10000+ messages per second.  I use the SQL Server CLR integration feature to define a CLR function which runs .NET Regex's on the messages.  For example, "select dbo.IsProfanity( Response ) from Responses" would complete in under a second for about 10000 rows of data with Responses up to 4000 characters long, running up to 200 Regexes (one or more variations for each swear word).  The function is flagged as deterministic so SQL server can handle multi-threading decisions.

Comment: @Triynko - Those are pretty good results. It's been a while since we last tested regular expressions and hardware has gotten much faster, so that is probably part of why your results are so fast. Though, it looks like your case is much simpler than ours. We had 10,000+ regular expressions rather than 200. We still feel that regular expressions aren't the best solution for the problem. Plus, CleanSpeak has also gotten faster on modern hardware. It now handles nearly 50,000 messages per second.

Answer (score 4):

Can you make use of any of the built-in character classes, e.g.

```
 \bf\W?o\W?o\W?\b
```

to detect "foo" with any non-letters between the letters, but not "food" or "snafoo" (sic)

However, the weakness of this is that "_" counts as a word character :-(

I think a more promising approach is to use a simple, fast filter with some false positives, then re-test the positives against a more rigorous filter. Unless your users are total potty-mouths, there shouldn't be all that many detailed checks needed.

**Update**: Thought of this after I went home, but *Qtax* got there first (see other answer) - try removing all the punctuation first, then run plain word patterns on the text. This should make the word patterns much simpler and faster, especially when you have a lot of words to test.

Finally, note that within `[]` you don't need to escape regex special characters, so:

```
[.,;:*`'^+~\\/#|]
```

is OK (backslash still needs escaping)

Comment: I just tested your regex against mine in a benchmark, mine was 50% faster for some reason, but the suggestion you have toward fast then slow check is a great idea.

Comment: @Bubby4j yours is faster probably because it will match strings that contain "bar" (so it finishes faster without traversing the rest of the word)?

Comment: I don't think so, because it'll even detect a space in it.

Comment: yes.. the point is that the speed depends on the data, i'd suggest tweak the performance for cases without any matches (i.e. polite language)

Comment: First, you cannot use `\b` in Java: it is broken before Java 7. Second, the right answer involves character properties, like `\pL`, or even `\p{alpha}`.

Answer (score 1):

When you have many words, group them by their first equal characters, and you should see less than linear time increase for added words.

I mean that if you have two words "foobar" and "fook" make a regex formed like `foo(?:bar|k)`.

Using non-backtracking groups instead of non-capturing might increase performance. I.e. replace `(?:...)` with `(?>...)`.

Another suggestion could be to just remove all the punctuation in the string first and then you could apply a simpler expression.

Also, if you can, try to apply the expression on longer strings. As that would probably be faster than doing one message at a time. Maybe combine several messages for a first check.

Comment: The `?:` vs `?>` made a good difference of 37%, nice suggestion.

Comment: @Bubby4j, if `foo` is a word on your list, you want words like `fuozo` to match? Because that's what your current expression will match. That doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: that's a good point. Hopefully there's not too many words like that, I'll just add them to a whitelist. My goal is to make something like http://www.inversoft.com/cleanspeak-capabilities/filtering/ , they claim that it only takes 1ms to filter a chat message, for all those really interesting possiblities.

Comment: Such a whitelist could not really be complete. Sounds like an awful solution imo. Afacs the examples you link to do not include random insertion of letters in the word.

Comment: that's a good point, I don't think I need to worry about extra letters.

Comment: @Bubby4j, in that case removing the punctuation first and then just matching the words is equivalent to your expression, and should be much faster.

Comment: +1 for suggesting removing all the punctuation first - I was going to add that to my answer but sleep intervened ;-)

Comment: Be careful when removing punctuation because sometimes they are important and other times they act like spaces.

Comment: @Brian, yes they are, but that's what his original expression already does.

Comment: @Qtax his original solution isn't handling punctuation quite correctly. It is more difficult than just looking for punctuation and/or whitespace between characters. There are a lot of issues that come up with handling separators (whitespace and certain punctuation) and replacement characters (leet speek and the like).

Comment: @Brian, there is no "correct" way to do this (with regex) at all. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to replace all

```
[.,;:*`'^+~\\/#|]+
```

with empty strings and then simply check for

```
\b(foo|bar)\b
```

**UPDATE:**

if you are more paranoid about the spaces `f( *+)o\1o|b( *+)a\2r`

or more paranoid in general `f([^o]?)o\1o|b([^a]?)a\2r`

Comment: Not flexible enough, people can easily get around the filter with that.

Comment: what foo-based example would not be matched that would be matched by the original? please note, that the original also has a lot of false negatives and positives, e.g. `frovo` - see http://regexr.com?3045m